# VUEJS: Override function from node_modules component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, node-modules

I have installed the `vue2-datepicker` component with `npm install vue2-datepicker` (Reference: https://openbase.com/js/vue2-datepicker). All is good and the plugin is working nice. The problem I am facing is that the week number of a new year is considered to be the week where January 1st is. Currently that is not correct so I have tried to override the function that is calculating it.

I have tried several approaches:

- `export` the function try to edit it and export the component again
- Use `extend` and just create a function with the same name
- `import` the component and access its methods and assign the old function to new function

None of the mentioned approaches worked.

My question is: **Is there a way to override a function that exist in a imported component located in `node_modules` folder using VUEJS?**

Comment: Yes - you can patch the code with the help of https://www.npmjs.com/package/custompatch

Comment: Either bring up an issue on the official package repo or fork it and make it your own with the modified code.